# Want to realize this operation (multiplication of divergent integrals of polynomials) in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, integral-transforms

I am currently researching divergent integrals.

1. **Definition.** An extended number is an expression of the form $\int_a^b f(x)dx$, where function $f(x)$ is defined almost everywhere at $(a,b)$. Generally (when Riemann or Lebesque sum converges or when the equivalence follows from the rules expressed below), an extended number can be equal to a real or complex number.
2. There are four simple equivalence rules based on linearity:

$\int_a^c f(x) dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_b^c f(x)dx$

$\int_a^b (f(x)+g(x)) dx=\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_a^b g(x)dx$

$\int_a^b c f(x) dx =c \int_a^b f(x) dx$

$\int_{-\infty}^{-a} f(x) dx=\int_a^\infty f(-x) dx$

3. There is one complicated Laplace-transform based rule:

$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)]\left(x\right)dx=\int_0^\infty\frac1x\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t[ f(t)]\left(x\right)dx$

4. There is a rule that allows to represent divergent integrals of polynomials via the most basic divergent integral $\tau=\int_0^\infty dx$:

$\int_0^\infty x^n dx=\frac{\left(\tau +\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}-\left(\tau -\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

5. Following Laplace transform, there is a similar rule (for $n>1$):

$\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^n} dx=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_0^\infty x^{n-2} dx=\frac{\left(\tau +\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\tau -\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}{(n-1)n!}$

6. There is the opposite rule, converting in the opposite direction:

$\tau^n=B_n(1/2)+n\int_0^\infty B_{n-1}(x+1/2)dx$

---

That said, one can use these rules to multiply divergent integrals of polynomials.

**Example.**

$\int_0^\infty \left(2x^3-3x^2+x-4\right) dx \cdot \int_0^\infty \left(2x^2-3x+1\right) dx=\left(\frac{2 \tau ^3}{3}-\frac{3 \tau ^2}{2}+\frac{7 \tau }{6}-\frac{1}{8}\right)
   \left(\frac{\tau ^4}{2}-\tau ^3+\frac{3 \tau ^2}{4}-\frac{17 \tau
   }{4}+\frac{23}{480}\right)=\frac{\tau ^7}{3}-\frac{17 \tau ^6}{12}+\frac{31 \tau ^5}{12}-\frac{83 \tau ^4}{16}+\frac{5333
   \tau ^3}{720}-\frac{4919 \tau ^2}{960}+\frac{1691 \tau }{2880}-\frac{23}{3840}=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{7 x^6}{3}-\frac{17 x^5}{2}+10 x^4-\frac{41 x^3}{3}+\frac{1007
   x^2}{60}-\frac{63 x}{10}-\frac{113}{120}\right)  dx+\frac{127}{420}$

---

I did the previous example by hand. Is it possible to optimally realize it in Mathematica?

I mean, 1. Enter the coefficients of two polynomials under the integrals 2. Obtain the coefficients of the resulting polynomial under integral plus the free term.

I suspect, this may be some kind of convolution.

Comment: Looks like esoteric math :). Assuming there is some interesting application. In any case, why there is no MA code? Someone has to do the typing!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

The operator looks like this:

$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx\cdot\int_0^\infty g(x)dx=\int_0^\infty D^2 \Delta^{-1} \left(\Delta D^{-2}f(x)\cdot\Delta D^{-2}g(x)\right) dx +D \Delta^{-1} \left(\Delta D^{-2}f(x)\cdot\Delta D^{-2}g(x)\right)|_{x=0}$

Here $\Delta D^{-2}f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}\int_0^s f(t)\,dt\,ds$.

The formula is unambiguous. Here is the Mathematica code:

```
f[x_] := x
g[x_] := x

Func := D[
    D[Sum[(DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]*DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]), x], x], x]
Const := (D[
     Sum[(DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]*DifferenceDelta[Integrate[Integrate[g[t], {t, 0, x}], x], 
         x]), x], x] /. x -> 0) 
Inactivate[
 Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]\[CenterDot]Integrate[
   g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], Integrate] == 
Const + Integrate[Func, {x, 0, Infinity}] // Simplify // Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

Out:=$\int _0^{\infty }xdx\cdot \int _0^{\infty }xdx=\int_0^{\infty } \left(x^3-\frac{x}{6}\right)
   \, dx+\frac{1}{180}$

The code works with polynomials, with exponential and trigonometric functions. As well as with convergent integrals (one can try $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx\cdot\int_0^\infty e^{-x}dx$ so to obtain $1$).

The code fails to produce an answer only when Mathematica's (discrete) integrator fails.